# Loop through ICollection and set to null

Tags: c#, loops, collections

I need to remove the data from an ICollection if the ID of the collection is in a List of ID's.

What I have so far:

```
    foreach (var notSelectedToolId in notSelectedToolIds)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matchingHoleInfoVm.ToolHeader.Count; i++)
        {
            if (matchingHoleInfoVm.ToolHeader.ElementAt(i).ToolID == notSelectedToolId)
            {
                matchingHoleInfoVm.ToolHeader.ElementAt(i) = new ToolHeaderViewModel();
            }
        }
    }
```

The error I get: `"This expression cannot be used as an assignment target"`.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, basically - not with *just* `ICollection` (or even `ICollection<T>`). Neither of them allow you to replace an existing element with a new one.

With `IList<T>`, it's pretty easy:

```
var list = matchingHoleInfoVm.ToolHeader;
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if (list[i].ToolID == notSelectedToolId)
    {
        list[i] = new ToolHeaderViewModel();
    }
}
```

In most cases where you've already got an `ICollection<T>`, you'll find it already implements `IList<T>`. If it doesn't, you need to look carefully at what the collection actually *is*, and consider whether "replace at the same index" even makes sense. (If it's a `HashSet<,>`, for example, you can just remove the existing item and add a new one...)

EDIT: If you only need to remove the items, you can just use the `Remove` method:

```
var itemsToRemove = collection.Where(c => c.ToolID == notSelectedToolId).ToList();
                              .ToList();
foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
{
    collection.Remove(item);
}
```

Additionally, you don't need nested loops - you can use something like:

```
var itemsToRemove = collection.Where(c => notSelectedToolIds.Contains(c.ToolID))
```

to find *all* of the ones to remove in a single pass (then remove them as above).

Comment: Any LINQ based approach?

Comment: @haim770: No. LINQ is for querying, not modifying collections.

Comment: I know, I meant a Linq query that will end up as a new `List<ToolHeaderViewModel>`.

Comment: @haim770 The question is specifically asking to mutate a collection, not create a new collection.

Comment: @JonSkeet It doesn't need to be a "replace at the same index". I just need a way to remove the elements that are currently there.

Comment: @user3738893: Then you should `Remove` instead. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I think my code and title were misleading to what I wanted, but your edit works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a filter to the `matchingHoleInfoVm.ToolHeader` using LINQ to return a new list. Something like

```
var toolsExlcuded = matchingHoleInfoVm.ToolHeader.Where(x => !notSelectedToolIds.Contains(x.ToolId)).ToList();
```

Comment: You can *remove* (using the `Remove` method) - you just can't *replace*.

Comment: Indeed. My mistake. Removed that bit.